# reverse enumerate with brackets

Tags: enumerate, etaremune

I would like to list my publications like this:

```
[3]

[2]

[1]
```

I found a solution to the brackets, using

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}]
```

and to the inverse numbering, with `etarenume`. But if I try to combine both, that is

```
\usepackage{etarenume}

\begin{etarenume}[label={[\arabic*]}]

\end{etarenume}
```

it does not work. Can anybody help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 13):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{[\theenumi]}   %%<------------------- this
\begin{document}
  \begin{etaremune}
    \item some item
    \item again some 
    \item some more
    \item some item
    \item again some
    \item some more
    \item some item
    \item again some
    \item some more
    \item some item
    \item again some
    \item some more
  \end{etaremune}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If it is for publications, and if you are using bibtex, there are better ways.

Comment: @eta90 Happy that it works. Please remember that you can up vote and accept (by clicking the green check mark next to it) the answer that you feel solved your problem. For details please read [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)